# How to setup the associations for an "Options" model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-activerecord

If had had the models `Store`, `Product`, `User` and `Price` with the following associations

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :stores
  has_many :prices
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :prices
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :prices
end

class Price < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :store
end

class Estate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And want to create a `Option` model that holds the models specific option type with things like, if an Estate has a backyard, swimming pool, tennis court or a price has a deal, discount or buy one get one free. Would this be done by a polymorphic association? 
I'm doing this so I don't have to create a Option model for each model and can just have one model for all new options I want to add. So is this the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a polymorphic option model, then the fields would be the same for each class/record an object belongs to. I don't think this is what you want since a deal doesn't have a swimming pool and an estate isn't buy-one-get-one (I wish!).

I would look into using [Rails 3.2 and the ActiveRecord::Store feature](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html). With this, just add a single text column to your model(s) (call it "options") and then you can define all the options you need.

```
class Estate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  store :options, accessors: [ :backyard, :pool, :tennis, :butler, :wine_cellar ]
end

estate = Estate.new
estate.pool = true
estate.options[:number_of_sharks] = 3 # Attributes not defined as accessors work too
```

Comment: Lol @ the buy-one-get-one-free estate. If I was using Rails 3.1, would I have to make a `Price Options` and `Estate Options` to do what I want to do?

Comment: Well, you could still use a polymorphic options model for all but you'd have to put ALL the options in there and add more logic to your views (not recommended). OR you could just put the options directly into the models/tables but that's not recommended if you need arbitrary ones or they will change often (lots of migrations).